# update 2 fields in Access database with Excel data and probably a Macro

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

In my master database I have a small table that contains two dates and ID numbers. I use this table for updating queries and do some analysis. The table looks like this:

```
Number   | Date  
1        | 09.07.2012.  
2        | 10.07.2012.
```

The thing I would like to do is to have an excel file that pops-up a form after startup.

That form should contain 2 fields and 2 buttons. In those fields I input 2 dates (with date picker or whatever) and with 1st button I update mentioned table in Access with fresh data (delete old dates and update with new ones) and with the other I start a predefined Macro in that Access database.

How complicated is this? can you guide me to the solution? Some sample code would be excellent.

```
Command25_Click() 
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM Datumi" 
Dim tbl As Recordset 

Set tbl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Datumi") 
tbl.AddNew tbl!brojka = "1" 
tbl!datum = Text8.Value 
tbl.Update 
tbl.AddNew tbl!brojka = "2" 
tbl!datum = Text10.Value 
tbl.Update
```

Comment: It is pretty easy to update, but what does the macro do?

Comment: if you mean macro in access, it just runs 20 or so predefined queries... those queries use the dates in the small table for filtering data.

Comment: In that case, it would be better to do the whole lot from the Excel end, rather than starting an instance of MS Access to run the macro. I will leave aside why Excel comes into it at all. I will add some notes.

Comment: Access comes into the combination because the reports i have to provide for some people must be in that excel file and im trying to avoid them doing anything on the db. so i would like to make it possible for them to just enter those dates and pull the reports by themselves without making any mess in the db.

Answer (score 0):

This is going the long way about to a certain extend because I am using the update of the dates to demonstrate how you might also run the saved queries.

```
'SQL for stored query, this assumes you
'will be updating based on some key
UPDATE DatesTable t
SET t.Date1 = [@Date1], t.Date2 = [@Date2]
WHERE t.aAuto=[@Key]

'Code for Excel
'You could set a library reference to 
'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library
Dim cmd As Object
Dim cn As Object

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Connection string, see also http://connectionstrings.com
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source=z:\docs\test.accdb"

cn.Open strCon

'Name of the saved query
cmd.CommandText = "UpdateDates"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

'Some parameters.
'http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/met_comm_createparameter.asp
'Make sure you get the type right, you will find details here:
'http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/ado_datatypes.asp
'You will find direction here:
'http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_para_direction.asp

'Make sure you get the order right
'adDate = 7, adInteger = 3, adParamInput = 1
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Date1", 7, 1, , txtDate1)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Date2", 7, 1, , txtDate2)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Date2", 3, 1, , MyUniqueKey)

'recs : return for records affected
'adExecuteNoRecords = 128 : no records are returned by this query, 
'so this increases efficiency
'http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/ado_ref_command.asp

cmd.Execute recs,,128

'Did it work?
MsgBox "Records updated: " & recs
```

Comment: thanks for the code. What did you mean by updating based on some key? this is pretty new to me so i guess im asking some stupid questions... also, if i undestand right, your SQL query suggests that the table has 1 column for date1 and other for date2... My table is first column ID, second column Dates.

Comment: The above is not a cut and paste, it is a guide with references. You not only want to update the dates table, but also to run a number of other queries. "Some key" means an ID or other key field. Your explanation is not detailed, so it is difficult to tell whether you are simply emptying the table and adding new rows or updating existing rows based on the ID (some key). If your table contains just two rows with dates, it seems like an irrelevant table, so I cannot tell if you are asking about a real table or an example.

Comment: So where are you getting stuck adapting my example to your requirements? Remember you also asked how you would run 20 other queries.