# Querying DB with ADODB Always Shows Error 'Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted'

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado, adodb

I can fetch data using DAO method, but in my current company the IT Dept. prohibit me adding reference other than ADO. So I want to use ADODB method to fetch data from Query.
These data will be used as a row source data for ListView.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub FillListView()

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lstItem As ListItem
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qrySavedQuery"
    rs.Open strSQL, CurrentProject.Connection

    With Me.ListView1
        'Set ListView Style
        .View = lvwReport
        .GridLines = True
        .FullRowSelect = True
        'Clear Headers and List Items
        .ListItems.Clear
        .ColumnHeaders.Clear
    End With

    'Setup Column Headers
    With Me.ListView1.ColumnHeaders
        .Add , , "Col1", 1000, lvwColumnLeft
        .Add , , "Col2", 2000, lvwColumnCenter
        .Add , , "Col3", 1000, lvwColumnCenter
        .Add , , "Col4", 1000, lvwColumnCenter
        .Add , , "Col5", 1700, lvwColumnCenter
        .Add , , "Col6", 800, lvwColumnCenter
        .Add , , "Col7", 1000, lvwColumnCenter
    End With

    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        Set lstItem = Me.ListView1.ListItems.Add()
        lstItem.Text = rs!col1
        lstItem.SubItems(1) = rs!col2
        lstItem.SubItems(2) = rs!col3
        lstItem.SubItems(3) = rs!col4
        lstItem.SubItems(4) = rs!col5
        lstItem.SubItems(5) = rs!col6
        lstItem.SubItems(6) = rs!col7
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Calls the routine above from the Load Event and ListView shows no data at all (with error '*Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted*')

If I change using DAO method, everything is okay. All data from the query can be fetched without problem.

What did I do wrong? Is this error because I am using Query instead of Table? If yes, what should I do?

**EDIT**

My Query

```
SELECT t2.col1, t2.[pmu-sn] & "/" & t2.[seedcheck_id] AS col2, 
Nz(t2.[amount],0)-Nz(t3.[delivery_amount],0) AS col3, t4.col4,
t4.col5, t4.col6, t4.col7
FROM (t1 INNER JOIN (t2 LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.seedcheckdtl_id = t3.seedcheckdtl_id) ON t1.[pmu-sn] = t2.[pmu-sn]) INNER JOIN t4 ON (t2.[pmu-sn] = t4.[pmu-sn]) AND (t1.[pmu-sn] = t4.[pmu-sn])
WHERE (((Nz([amount],0)-Nz([delivery_amount],0))<>0) AND ((t2.seedcheck_id) Like "*-PC*"))
ORDER BY t1.pmu_bunch_id, t2.[pmu-sn] & "/" & [seedcheck_id], t2.[pmu-sn], t2.seedcheck_id;
```

Hope this helps finding the problem.

**EDIT**

[image: Screenshot of my office PC.]

Picture taken from my Office PC. No DAO folder in it. And I can't copy it without IT Dept. approval.
BTW I create the Access app in my own laptop which is also Office 2013.

Comment: did you try with a table ?

Comment: Yes, and no problem fetching data from table.

Comment: is `qrySavedQuery` a table name?

Comment: No, it's a saved query name.

Comment: Maybe just remove the `SELECT * FROM` then, leaving just the query name (based on answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399672/execute-query-from-access-via-excel-query-in-vba)

Comment: Already remove that, still same error. Also using the proposed way from the thread. I am using `dim cmd as new adodb.command` way, but still no luck. All 7 fields in the recordset can be fetch but still no value returned (same as result from my sample code above).

Comment: Does your query contain user-defined functions or parameters obtained from reports or forms? Perhaps sharing the query can help.

Comment: Maybe `Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM qrySavedQuery")` will work? Or maybe it's a matter of cursor type?

Comment: *but in my current company the IT Dept. prohibit me adding reference other than ADO* - are they insane? DAO is the native data access library in Access (except ca. Access 2000).

Comment: Add to Andre's reaction that you don't need to add a reference to use DAO. It's native to Access, so you can always use it inside Access.

Comment: Note that doing movefirst or movelast when there are no records will fire error 3021: no current record. check for records first (if not .bof and not .eof).

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @erik-von-asmuth my query already inserted in my question above. @andre What I meant by prohibit adding DAO, there is no DAO folder in MS Shared Foklder (where dao360 files usually resides), and i cant add it by myself without knowing admin pwd. Even using Left or Right function is impossible. @brainac The cursor type is adOpenStatic. @wazz & @rbarry If i add `if (not rs.bof and not rs.eof)` before `rs.MoveFirst`, no error shows up. There is no line with error, but no data fetched. I even removed error handler code. I found out the cause by looking at `rs` in WATCH window.

Comment: @brainac If I change into 'set rs' like you mention above, still no data with the same error.

Comment: Please add to your question: 1) your Access version, 2) a screenshot of your References window. -- The old DAO 3.6 reference and DLL is indeed obsolete for newer Access versions (since 2007, I think), but for .accdb the new ACE (MS Office 14 Access database engine Object Library = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.DLL) should fulfill all DAO needs. (Example = Office 2010)

Comment: @y2a Maybe Nz() is an issue then? I don't know how it exactly works when you call stored query, but I'm almost sure you can't use it in ADO queries directly.

Comment: @Andre I am using Office 2013. I will upload my Ref's screenshot in the body of my question above.

Comment: @brainac If that the case, is there any workaround or alternative of Nz()?

Comment: @y2a It is equivalent of `IIF(t2.[amount] IS NOT NULL, t2.[amount], 0)` I believe.

Comment: This is an .accdb, not a .mdb, right? There should be `Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library` in that References list - check that and uncheck the old `DAO 3.6`.

Comment: @Andre Cant find it. Did you mean `Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library`?

Comment: @brainac Ok I will try it. Thanks

Comment: No, this should be the exact name. https://www.google.com/search?q="Microsoft+Office+15.0+Access+database+engine+Object+Library"

Comment: Oh... i found it. I will try this one on my office pc. Will update the progress soon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

rs.MoveLast

before your rs.MoveFirst

this will iterate through entire recordset and place the cursor properly.  I seem to recall doing this will mitigate the issue you are experiencing...

Comment: Try it but still no luck. :(